# mootools replace the content of a div

Tags: javascript, mootools

i have the following HTML code

```
<div id="myDiv">
   <p>content</p>
</div>
```

and the following JS code:

```
$('myDiv').set('html',htmlCode);
```

the problem is that the variable htmlCode is something like:

```
<div id="myDiv"><p>another content</p></div>
```

so, the result when i run the JS code is something like:

```
<div id="myDiv">
   <div id="myDiv">
      <p>another content</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

is there a way to use "set" so that it overrides the entire div? or another solution to get something like:

```
<div id="myDiv">
   <p>another content</p>
</div>
```

as the result from the JS script?
i know i could just change the variable htmlCode... i just was wondering if there's another solution to this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mootools offers a simple [replaces](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#Element:replaces) method!

```
//new tmp element that contains the new div
var tmpDiv = new Element('div',{html:'<div id="myDiv"><p>another content</p></div>'});

//new div (first child of my tmp div) replaces the old 'myDiv' (that can be grabbed from the DOM by $)
tmpDiv.getFirst().replaces($('myDiv'));
```

Comment: thanks, it works!! i voted for the "implemented" approach as the accepted answer, but i realized that yours is simpler and... it's in mootools core!!

Answer (score 5):

```
String.implement({
    replaces: function(toReplace) {
        Elements.from(this).inject(toReplace, 'after');
        toReplace.destroy();
    }
});

'<div id="a"><p>ipsum</p></div>'.replaces($('a'));
```

This should do. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/UvuwG/

Answer (score 4):

```
$('myDiv').empty();
$('myDiv').adopt(Elements.from(htmlCode).getElement('p'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
$("myDiv").getParent().set("html", htmlCode);
```

Comment: this will only works if the parent only contains the div with the id myDiv